# How Can I Run the python programs on Docker using active containers with the VS Code?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I want to run Kafka producer / consumer and connect them to the Broker using VS Code.

1- I have already run a Kafka Broker with the docker-compose, with an active Kafka container. 
How can I use the Kafka container without installing it locally ?

I have installed the kafka library on my local machine, and everything worked perfectly..

Expected: Using the Kafka container instead of the local lib.

Comment: Maybe you should share your Python code, and what isn't working with it

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this with the assumption that when you say you machine, you're referring to your local machine (I would comment directly on your question ask for clarification, but I don't have enough rep yet). Installing a library locally allows for it to work locally, but not in other environments. So you need to install the Kafka library within the environment you're targeting, too.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to my local machine, I have installed the Kafka docker image using “docker pull confluentinc/cp-kafka”  and I want to use it instead of the local machine environment.

Comment: @Zouari then use Compose or docker run commands explicitly. Your Python code still needs to install Kafka client libraries, though, but that's completely separate

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the Kafka container without installing it locally ?

Not clear what "it" is... The Docker image? That's not how Docker works.

You need to <strike>install</strike> pull the Docker image locally in order to use it

> I have installed the kafka library on my local machine

I assume that you mean something downloaded from kafka.apache.org? If that's the case, no, you don't need that for Python

You will instead have to pip install some Kafka Python package and write code to communicate to the Kafka container

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to connect to a container or a remote machine using VS Code. Please see the [instructions for remote development in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) on how to remotely connect to containers or machines via SSH.